# OracleDependency + SignalR

Tags: asp.net, oracle, oracle11g

I want do an application with OracleDependency + SignalR, I follow the documentation and I do this steps:

Activate this commands on Oracle

```
grant change notification to SN_Hospitales;
GRANT EXECUTE ON DBMS_CHANGE_NOTIFICATION TO SN_Hospitales;
```

Then I have this code with .Net

```
var Entidad= "sn_hospitales.entidad_dependency";
var login = "DATA SOURCE=(DESCRIPTION = " +
            " (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 192.168.54.170)(PORT = 1521)) " +
            " (CONNECT_DATA = " +
            " (SERVER = DEDICATED) " +
            " (SERVICE_NAME = SERUD) " +
            " ))   ; USER ID=SN_Hospitales;PASSWORD=XXXXXX";

OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection(login);
con.Open();
OracleDependency dependency = new OracleDependency();
OracleCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
string sql = "select nombre from " + Entidad;
cmd.CommandText = sql;
dependency.OnChange += new OnChangeEventHandler(dep_OnChange);
dependency.AddCommandDependency(cmd);
cmd.Notification.IsNotifiedOnce = false;
cmd.AddRowid = true;
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

But the application doesn't work, anyone can help me?

Comment: What does it mean? How it "doesn't work"? Do you get error or just effect is different than you expected?

Comment: No error, Oracle doesn't warn me when I change something in the Table